# I have "broken pipe" exception using Sockets and Netty. What's wrong?

Tags: java, sockets, netty, protocol-buffers, broken-pipe

guyz!

I have some protobuf objects to send to server.
Server uses Netty.

When I use Netty for client with Netty's `ProtobufDecoder`, all goes nice.

But when I try to send protobuf object through vanilla Java `Socket`, I have "broken pipe" exception. But Socket object stay connected and I can send another object and get exception again. =(

Here is netty-based client's pipeline setup:

```
ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();
pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder", new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(134217728, 0, 4, 0, 4));
pipeline.addLast("protobufDecoder", new ProtobufDecoder(mSocketListener.getInMessage()));
```

I don't know, where to specify `maxFrameLength` and other params.

Here is error log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:141)
at SocketClientMain.main(SocketClientMain.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

What's going wrong?
May be I have broken hands?
Or I need to ask server-owner for some info?

Comment: providing an error log would be nice

Comment: @Nordenheim, sorry, fixed

Comment: @KartoshkaMan Did you fix your issue ?

Answer (score 3):

`java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe` is caused by trying to write to a connection, while the other side has already closed that same connection. It is not you, who closed the connection, else another exception would have been thrown. You can not recover the connection, you have to open a new one.

Or in case you keep getting the exception, it just simply means the application protocol is poorly defined or poorly implemented.

Comment: hm...so...
I don't know where to find information about defining sockets in right way.
I think, something goes wrong because of I don't know how to translate this part of code into vanilla sockets setup: `new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(134217728, 0, 4, 0, 4)`

Comment: The constructor itself is described [here](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.html#LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). I can't really help you with Netty beyond that, because I've never worked with Netty.

Answer (score 0):

I think to add the  setting: spring.codec.max-in-memory-size={larger size}MB into system property before startup.
it may solve the broken pipe exception.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35220551)